# How to display an independent window that displays a video feed in my app in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, dialog, widget, popupwindow

I'm making my app to display a small window, which is independent from my app's main activity, upon pressing a button. And the window will display a webcam preview.
At first, I was thinking dialog box, but it looks like the box has to be very simple (please correct me if I'm wrong).
So I thought about a simple popup window from main activity, but also simple.
Lastly, I chose to use an activity which will display a small window, but it is not independent from main activity meaning that background view freezes as long as the window is displayed.
Which approach should I take to achieve that? popup window? dialog box? fragment? can I make fragment small enough that I can still see the background activity?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

edit-------------------------------onCreate() in popup activity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_video);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .3), (int) (height * .2));
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = -20;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a popup activity with a VideoView and the following style

```
<style name="popupTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This will make the popup activity float above and you can see the other activity in the background.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One more question, J. Doe. when I set up my style as above, I can see what's going on in my background (main activity), but I can't touch or do anything as long as the popup activity is not dismissed. Please see "edit" for my popup activity onCreate().

Comment: No you can't interact with the main activity. But I think the only way to show a video and interact with the main activity is to add a video view to the main activity. Because if you create a new activity, the new activity will be selected.

Comment: Got you. Thank you!!